# How to add ontap marker on googlemap in flutterflow?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps, flutterflow

I need to show multiple markers on a Google Map in **FlutterFlow**. Additionally, I would like to display a bottom sheet when a marker is clicked. However, it appears that there is no straightforward way to achieve this. Could someone provide more details about whether this is possible or not?

I try use to custom function

Comment: dis you find answer from here? https://docs.flutterflow.io/widgets-and-components/widgets-ui-elements/base-elements/googlemap

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows what you have tried so far, the challenges you encountered, or details that would increase your chances of getting help. You can also read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve the quality of your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.